# What are some good resources for branding exercises or workshops?

Tags: branding, client-relations, conceptualization, identity

I have the chance to set up the branding for a friend's start up business. We're not looking at actual logos just yet, just trying to work out a voice, look and feel for the business - map out what their values and identity are.

I've done workshops for customer needs and business needs but don't know any for helping with branding.

Does anyone know of any good books or websites that have ideas for this?

Comment: Browse questions here under the "Branding" tag and you'll get lots of advice on "how to."

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this it may help.....

1. http://www.logodesignlove.com/brand-identity-style-guides
2. http://playfoursquare.s3.amazonaws.com/press/foursquare-brandbook.pdf
3. Tres Logos-----book
4. Build ur own Brand  by Robin landa----book

Comment: Why not link the book or provide the ISBN?